# Find range of $f(x)=3\cos^4x-6\cos^3x-6\cos^2x-3$ in the interval $[-π/2, π/2]$

Tags: functions

While solving some questions related to functions, I came across this question and I am unable to find  its range.

$$f(x)=3\cos^4x-6\cos^3x-6\cos^2x-3$$in the interval $[-π/2, π/2]$

I tried graphing this function on Desmos and got this result.

[image: Desmos graph for f(x)]

However, since I can't use a graphing tool in exams, I need to be able to solve this algebraically.

When I tried factorising the function, I could only get this far:

$$f(x)=3(\cos x+1)(\cos^3x-3\cos^2x+\cos x-1)$$

Can anyone help how to solve this further?

Comment: Do you know curve sketching techniques (CST-1)? I can explain if you know that basic. With that , you may or may not need to factorise your equation also.

Comment: @Srijan M.T What do you mean by "curve sketching" ? The study of variations using differentiation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie No. It used to graph various functions from basic properties.

Comment: Yes, I do know a decent amount of curve sketching

Comment: @JeanMarie Basically , not with calculus.

Comment: @Srijan M.T Can you give a reference ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have told about to users in my chat room as well. There are total 6 CST. My teacher taught me actually. I don’t know of a link.

Comment: @JeanMarie I’ll paste an image of CST 3 here. One sec.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5rY.jpg. This is only for quadratics. Proofs are on different page.

Comment: @JeanMarie For trigonometry, there are a lot. I think they may have a different name. But my teacher calls it CST.

Comment: @ Srijan M.T Thanks!

Comment: @Navya Is my (re-edited) solution understandable at your level ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x)=3x^4-6x^3-6x^2-3$; then $f(x)=\varphi\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)$.

If $x\in[0,1]$, you have $\varphi'(x)\leqslant0$ and $\varphi'(x)=0\iff x=0$. So, $\varphi$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$. Since $\varphi(0)=-3$ and $\varphi(1)=-12$, the range of the restriction of $\varphi$ to $[0,1]$ is $[-12,-3]$ (see the graph of $\varphi$ below). Since the range of $\cos$ on $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ is $[0,1]$, the range of $f(=\varphi\circ\cos)$ is also $[-12,-3]$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I got this :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: What software do you use to plot graphs?

Comment: @Joe Usually it's GeoGebra, but this time I did it with Mathematica.

Comment: Question.  How is the minimal value of the cosine $-1$ when the argument is in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution which does not use differentiation.

Let $$c=\cos \theta \in [0,1] \ \text{because} \ \theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$$

The given expression is

$$\varphi(c)=3c^4-6c^3-6c^2-3$$

Let us first observe that $\varphi(0)=-3$ and $\varphi(1)=-12$.

Therefore, according to the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem),
the range of $\varphi$ **contains** interval $[-12,-3]$.

Besides, let us express $\varphi(c)$ under the form:

$$\varphi(c)=3c^2((c-1)^2-3)-3 \tag{1}$$

As $0\le c \le 1$ , we have:

$$\begin{cases}-3&\le&(c-1)^2-3 &\le& -2\\
 \ \ \ 0 &\le& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3c^2& \le & \ \ \ 3\end{cases}$$

implying:

$$-9 \le 3c^2((c-1)^2-3) \le 0$$

A final subtraction gives:

$$-12 \le \underbrace{3c^2((c-1)^2-3)-3}_{\varphi(c)} \le -3$$

showing that the range of $\varphi$ is now **contained into** interval $[-12,-3]$.

As a consequence, the range of $f$ is precisely $[-12,-3]$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I very much liked your (non-Calculus) approach, except for the last paragraph.  Normally, such Topology concepts such as a **compact interval** or a **continuous mapping** are taught *after* Real Analysis, rather than before.  Although it may be very difficult, is there any way that you can re-write your last paragraph so that the idea being expressed is crystal clear in the pre-Calculus world?

Comment: @ user2661923 I appreciate your well-founded remark. I am going to attempt it. You will say me if the objective is reached.

Comment: +1 : nice editing.

Comment: @Navya Is my (re-edited) solution understandable at your level ?

Comment: To Jean Marie : your last comment flagged me, instead of the original poster.   For a comment that follows a specific answer or question, assuming that the addressee is not the originator of the answer or question, then the addressee is only flagged if they have *registered* for that question or answer, by first leaving a comment, following that question or answer.  Since Navya is **unregistered** for your answer, in order to flag Navya, you should leave a comment that follows the original question.

Comment: I understand. Sorry. Thanks for this explanation. Besides, thanks again for having suggested me to re-write my answer in a simpler way. I appreciate very much this type of exchanges.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes! Thank you so much, I am able to understand it well. Thanks for linking the Intermediate value theorem wiki page :)